# Once authenticated once, passwords are cached in lightdm

Tags: password, lightdm, authentication

We are preparing 12.04 LTS for our userbase and have done some basic configuration to the login screen (disabled guest account, removed user list, etc). However, one thing that I've noticed is that once a user has authenticated at the login screen (KRB5), a user will no longer have to enter their password. In fact, even after reboot, if a user has previously authenticated, all they have to do is type their username and they can login with no other prompts.

Obviously this is a major security risk at the enterprise level. Please let me know if you need any other information. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your consideration, but we've realized it is a GID conflict. We have an LDAP group with GID 112, which happens to be the GID of the nopasswdlogin group at least in Precise. We'll be migrating that LDAP group to another GID. This is just an FYI if others see this behavior by chance. I can't close this for another few hours.

Comment: Is the password being cached, or is it just not required? Perhaps this is a problem with pam-auth not requiring a password at all. Check out `etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

Comment: not too familiar with this file. It's just not prompting for a password after the first successful login. Here's what I see:  root@host:~# less /etc/pam.d/common-auth \n
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=256 \n
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so

Comment: I wanted to add that this file is identical on our 10.04 hosts, which do not exhibit this behavior. thanks!

Comment: Does not seam to be the problem.  Just a thought as an incorrectly configured pam-auth can subvert passwords.

Answer (score 1):

we've realized it is a GID conflict. We have an LDAP group with GID 112, which happens to be the GID of the nopasswdlogin group at least in Precise. We'll be migrating that LDAP group to another GID. This is just an FYI if others see this behavior by chance. I can't close this for another few hours.